# Want C# List<string> Serialization With BasicDesignerLoader As Text Not Binary To XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, windows-forms-designer

I have a subclassed TextBox designer component (WinForms control) that exposes a List property called `MyStringsList` in my C# WinForms application, defined like this:

```
private List<string> _myStringsList = new List<string>();

public List<string> MyStringsList
{
   get => _myStringsList;
   set => _myStringsList = value;
}
```

This control is used at runtime as a designer component on a BasicDesignerLoader design surface. When the TextBox control gets flushed and serialized to XML, I get this:

```
<Property name="BorderColor">Gray</Property>
<Property name="BorderStyle">FixedSingle</Property>
<Property name="MyStringsList">                     
  <Binary>AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAEAQAAAH9TeX...</Binary>
</Property>
...
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
<Property name="BorderColor">Gray</Property>
<Property name="BorderStyle">FixedSingle</Property>
<Property name="MyStringsList">                     
  <Value>My String 01</Value>
  <Value>My String 02</Value>
  <Value>My String 03</Value>
  ...
</Property>
```

I understand that I can take the binary-base64-encoded XML and decode it then rewrite the XML, but I am trying to avoid that post-processing step when serializing the XML to a file. I also understand that I might encounter some issues when deserializing the XML file back to a subclassed TextBox instance if I modify how the List object is serialized, but I think I can handle that when the XML needs to be deserialized.

What can I do with attributes (if anything) to force the .NET BasicDesignerLoader Flush() serializer to write my List objects as human-readable XML elements rather than as base64-encoded binary?